# Search engine on top of Nexus maven repository manager

Tags: maven, search, repository, nexus

We use Nexus as our maven repository manager, and while it does have a built in search/browse capabilities, it can be a little clunky to use. Is there a way to put an external search engine on top of the Nexus repository, such as the one the maven central repository uses (http://search.maven.org/) so it's a little easier to search/browse? Or is that a custom search engine for the Maven central repo only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search for Central is custom. What is the problem with the search in Nexus you are having?

In the extreme case you can implement your own indexer in a custom Nexus plugin and extend the search to work with it.

Or if you really want to create your own user interface you can access all the information from Nexus via the REST API and write your own search app.

Comment: It's not that I'm having any real problems with search, but I just think the maven central repo search engine is nice and easy to work with, so I wanted to have that more minimalist search capability. Browsing in nexus takes a few clicks to get to as well. I was just trying to make it a little more convenient for our Nexus users.

Comment: I am sure Sonatype would welcome any concrete improvement suggestions in the form of a jira ticket ;-)

Comment: Updated question with the hint to create your own app using the REST API.

Comment: @JeffStorey Raise an issue with the Sonatype guys. I'm sure they'd appreciate the feedback. I must admit I now find myself using the new Maven Central search site more and more

Comment: Well. Both are maintained by the Sonatype team ;-)

Comment: @ManfredMoser I signed up for a JIRA account to open the issue, but it says I do not have permission to login.